# LoRa Cloud PIN derivation according to 'smtc0' algorithm

Tags: hash, aes

I am following the steps in LoRa Cloud in order to derive the PIN value using the Algorithm smtc0 (https://www.loracloud.com/documentation/join_service?url=derivation_schemes.html).
I don't quite understand how the DMKEY(i) = (hash[0]+i mod 256) | hash[1] | .. | hash[15] is derived.